# Match algorithm

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am unsure how take data from an IEnum object and dump it to a Dictionary and/or List, and would appreciate any guidance.
I'm working on a program that sorts through a collection of data pulled from SQL DB. I'm using Enterprise Library 5 (Data Access Application Block). So far there is an adapter class that will create an instance of the DB, map the query results to appropriate fields (Namely: First, middle, last names, DoB, and an ID), and it has two methods of type IEnumerable that will pass the SQL statement. I am unsure of how the the return IEnum object looks like. One method will return a list of offenders and another will return a list of all the records based on DoB:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetOffenders()
{   
var people =
            _db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<Person>(@"SELECT pm.Local_ID, pm.First_Name, pm.Last_Name, pm.Middle_Name, pm.DOB 
                    FROM Person_Main pm ", _personRowMapper);

        return people;
```

}

In another class that will hold the matching logic, I am trying to "dump" the contents of the getOffenders() which was defined in the adapter class, the idea is iterate over the two lists (offenders and all records based on DoB). I'm assuming the a good route would be to use a Dictionary to hold the results from getOffenders(). So far I've got this test code, which only checks to see if the connection to the DB is successful and retrieves a row of dummy data I entered:

```
    PersonAdapter personAdapter = new PersonAdapter();
    private Dictionary<String, List<Person>> testDictionary = new Dictionary<String, List<Person>>();

    public void Test1()
    {
        var offenders = personAdapter.GetOffenders();
        var pList = new List<Person>();
        // Test to see if GetOffenders is returning data correctly
        foreach (var variable in offenders)
        {
            var fName = variable.FirstName;
            var mName = variable.MiddleName;
            var lName = variable.LastName;
            var lId = variable.LocalId;

            Console.WriteLine(variable.FirstName + " " + variable.MiddleName + " " +
                     variable.LastName + " " + variable.LocalId);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: What does your debugger show?

Comment: Maybe I missed something. What would be returning incorrectly from `GetOffenders()`? Your foreach will only iterate over your list if there is at least one item in there.

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but why are you dumping the values of the returned record to different variables and then not using them in your `WriteLine`?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish here.  Can you provide some more detail on the "match" algorithm you need, and perhaps sample input and output?  It could also be helpful if you posted code that shows what you really want to do (with comments where you need help filling things in) rather than dummy code that isn't really what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @gmiley there isn't anything wrong with the method itself. I'm having trouble understanding how the method return works (IEnumerable)... I can see that it its returning the appropriate values but I wish to pass these to a dictionary as opposed to simply calling console.writeLine

Comment: @LFHernandez add `using System.Linq;` if you don't already have it, then look up the extension methods [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261.aspx) and [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IEnumerable` implementation only returns one item at a time. If you want to transfer those to a static collection you will need to loop through the `IEnumerable` collection and then do a `List<Person>.Add(item)`.

```
foreach(var item in offenders)
{
    pList.Add(item);
}
```

Then you can use your `pList` collection as a normal `List<>` to then add to your `testDictionary` field.

```
testDictionary.Add("some_string_key", pList);
```